# Cейчас перенаправляет при вводе не существующей страницы на главную ,а не на 404,мне надо чтоб пользователь видел 404 ,как исправить?

Tags: php

```
# redirect all requests to index.php loader
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

ПРОБОВАЛ ВОТ ТАК ТОЖЕ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

```
# redirect all requests to index.php loader
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

      RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

      ErrorDocument 404 /err404.html

    </IfModule>
```

Comment: откуда куда?....

Comment: С не существующих страниц http://сайт/не существующая страница

Comment: на 404 страницу

Comment: Вопрос не имеет смысла в текущем виде, т.к. 404 и так отдается апачем в случае если страница не существует. если вы хотите изменить внешний вид страницы для ошибки 404 - так и пишите.

Comment: Cейчас перенаправляет при вводе не существующей страницы на главную ,а не на 404,мне надо чтоб пользователь видел 404 ,как исправить?

Comment: Вопрос имеет право быть, т.к. задать его правильно, не зная ответ, очень сложно.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков мне главное чтоб хоть какайто 404 была ,а не главная

Answer (score 3):

Браузер и сервер общаются по протоколу HTTP или HTTPS. При вводе адреса в адресную строку браузера или  при отправке формы происходят запросы определённого формата. В ответ на этот запрос сервер отравляет ответ определённого формата. Этот ответ включает в себя: версию протокола, результат запроса, заголовки и тело ответа. Код 404 - это один из множества результатов запроса. К примеру 403 (ошибка доступа), 500 (критическая ошибка сервера). По умолчанию сервер отправляет результат 200 (успешное выполнение). Страница же передаётся в теле ответа.

Т.е. для того чтобы получить собственную страницу с ошибкой 404. Вам надо отослать собственную страницу с результатом 404. Длю установки результата в php есть функция `http_response_code`.

Пример:

```
<?php 

$requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Простая адресация
if ($requestUri == '/') {
    drawMainPage();
} elseif ($requestUri == '/second') {
    drawSecondPage();
} else {
    drawNoFoundPage();
}

// Главная страница
function drawMainPage() {
    echo '<h1>My site</h1><hr><p>Main page</p>';
}

// Вторая страница
function drawSecondPage() {
    echo '<h1>My site</h1><hr><p>Second page</p>';
}

// Ошибка 404
function drawNoFoundPage() {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo '<h1>My site</h1><hr><p>Page not found</p>';
}
```

Устанавливать результат (функция `http_response_code`) как и вывод заголовков (функция `header`) необходимо делать раньше чем вывод тела ответа.

Comment: у него кмс, пиши ему модуль)))

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что никто это ещё не посоветовал. В `.htaccess` (за пределами `IfModule`):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /err404.html
```

И так по строчке для всех страниц и ошибок, которые нужны.

Comment: Так не работает   

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  

    RewriteEngine On  

    RewriteBase /  

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
 
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  

  </IfModule>  
  

   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html `

Comment: Что именно не работает? Существует ли файл `404.html`? Правильный ли путь к нему? Пробовали задать абсолютный путь типа `https://example.com/errors/404.html`?

Comment: Да, все равно да главеую выводит